# Write values in file in c#

Tags: c#, file, windows-runtime, windows

I am trying to write values to file in C#. I am trying to use either the following code:

```
 using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("values.txt"))
 {
            writer.Write("Word");
            writer.WriteLine("word 2");
            writer.WriteLine("Line");
 }
```

I got the error: `Error the best overloaded method match for System.IO.StranWriter.StreamWriter(System.IO.Stream)` has some invalid arguments.

or the following code:

```
string path = @"values.txt";

if (!File.Exists(path))
{
     // Create a file to write to. 
     using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
     {
            sw.WriteLine("Hello");
            sw.WriteLine("And");
            sw.WriteLine("Welcome");
     }
}
```

I got the following error: `The name 'File' does not exist in the current context`. When am I missing here?

EDIT: Basically I tried to change FIle to System.IO.File and I got the following message:`The type or namespace 'File' does not exist in the namespace System.IO(are you missing an assembly reference)`. My code is in a function which I call from public MainPage() function in windows Application.

EDIT2: I tried to follow the solution of the proposed duplicate post. I got the message that `await operator can only be used within an async method`.

Comment: Insert `using System.IO;` at the top of your code.

Comment: Isn't it `The name 'File' ...`?

Comment: Your `if(!File...` is the problem. You probably forgot to declare the using.

Comment: Show the declaration of pathFile. And ask 1 question per question, answers are now getting mixed up between 1st and 2nd problem.

Comment: Please show the real exceptions and don't write them here manually. Also the first exception-message is wrong: `System.IO.StranWriter.StreamWriter`

Comment: No people stop downvoting I have already define using System.IO

Comment: You have changed the error message -.-.

Comment: Could you show your variable `pathFile` in the first code-example?

Comment: string path = @"values.txt"; or using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("tet.txt"))

Comment: Read the comments here carefully and edit your question with the requested information.

Comment: Is this for regular .NET or for WinRT / Phone?  Tell us the version(s) being used.

Comment: We're still not seeing `pathFile`. Incomplete code is a close reason.

Comment: It is the same string pathFile = @"values.txt";

Comment: Edit your question then please. The comment-section isnt an extension for your question.

Comment: Edit that into your question. Also add tags for the relevant platform.

Comment: My app is a Blank App for Windows in C#

Comment: Re Edit2: Look up async/wait, it's a complex subject but a few good examples will get you going. Don't add follow-ups to a question, and this one would be a duplicate too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, we have to guess a lot here but it looks like you're writing a Phone, Store or Universal App.

The new Windows Runtime does not provide you with all the old synchronous classes and methods.

There is no `FileStream(string)` constructor and no static `IO.File` class on your platform.

Comment: I followed that instructions to create my project http://kinect.github.io/tutorial/lab01/index.html. It is a blank project for windows 8.1

Comment: Yes, big difference between an "App" and an "Application" here. You can't use the 'normal' I/O code samples you will find, look especially for WinRT.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest

```
IO.File.WriteAllText(fileFullPath, stringBuilder.ToString());
```

...instead of the StreamWriter.

Comment: Good idea but not really an answer.

Comment: I don't know, I wish someone gave me this answer when I started learning on my own. It would have saved me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

What i see is you are trying to write in stream object, 
Simply you can do by following code

```
 System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"{Filepath}","your text");
```

Please note using WriteAllText or ,,, will replace all the content with your new value.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like You're using `StreamWriter` correctly. If nothing helps, create new solution from scratch, console application and paste this code. It has to work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("test.txt"))
            {
                writer.Write("Line 1");
                writer.WriteLine("Still line 1");
                writer.WriteLine("Line 2");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously look for you `test.txt` file in bin folder

Comment: I got the same error.

Comment: Did you add `using System.IO;` ?

Comment: Yes!! I have already add System.IO

Comment: Instead of `pathFile` paste there hard-coded path like in my example. Did you try that?

Comment: This is how it should be done: http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamwriter

Comment: @JoseRamon You can create completely new project - console application, in different place. Paste my code and it must work.

Comment: Yes but my issue here that I wans a black windows app not a blank console application.